# Lua parser in python

Tags: python, lua, eval

I'm looking into using Lua in a web project. I can't seem to find any way of directly parsing in pure python and running Lua code in Python.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Joe

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you post your real problem, which  seems to be how to create a safe or sandboxed Lua environment for use in a web application.  People on the Lua list have done this N times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's this project ([pylux](http://www.equi4.com/wikis/lua/25)) which embeds Lua in Python. It seems rather inactive though, but it may be a good project to have a look at.

Comment: I'm looking for a Pure Python implementation

Comment: Good luck on finding a pure Python Lua parser (never heard of one though).

Comment: Hm... i've decided against using Lua. I'm just going to override the python builtins. This is a good answer though, so I'll mark it

Comment: @Joe, that doesn't sound like a good plan for making a good, working, maintainable program. Is your hope to sandbox Python? If so, that won't likely work well.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it appears you a interested in a secure way of executing untrusted code.

Redifining python builtins, as you suggested in a comment, is a horrible way to secure code.

What you want is sandboxing, there are solutions for python, but I wouldn't recommend them.  You would be much better of using Jython or IronPython, because the JVM and .NET clr, were designed with sandboxing in mind.

I personally believe that in most cases, if you need to execute untrusted code, then you are putting too much or not enough trust in your users.

Answer (score 1):

@the_drow

From Lua's web site:

> Lua is a fast language engine with small footprint that you can embed
>   easily into your application. Lua has a simple and well documented API
>   that allows strong integration with code written in other languages.
>   It is easy to extend Lua with libraries written in other languages. It
>   is also easy to extend programs written in other languages with Lua.
>   **Lua has been used to extend programs written not only in C and C++, but also in Java, C#, Smalltalk, Fortran, Ada, Erlang, and even in
>   other scripting languages, such as Perl and Ruby.**

@Joe Simpson

Check out Lunatic Python, it might have what you want.  I know it's an old question, but other people might be looking for this answer, as well.  It's a good question that deserves a good answer.